# VB.NET extract data from API

Tags: vb.net, basic

I am a beginner in VB.NET and i am trying to extract data from an API and add it to a listview column but i don't know how to extract the data.
[This is the API][1]
[1]: https://tmnf.exchange/api/tracks?author=lolsport&count=40&fields=TrackId%2CTrackName
It is a API for downloading race tracks for Trackmania.
The data is shown as follows  `{"TrackId":9707620,"TrackName":"lolsport R444"},`
Now what i need is the TrackIDs and TrackNames.
i have two columns in my program where i want to sort them into like so.

```
**TrackID**  **TrackName**
  9707620      lolsport R444
```

How can i do this? i googled a lot about regular expressions but i cant seem to find anything that works.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what part of it hasn't worked? I.e. post your source code.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! I made the UI and tried to get some data in to the columns but i have no idea how to do it. I have no code to show as i haven't had anything working yet. i did read many articles but none really contained what i need.

Comment: > i googled a lot about regular expressions. That is a suboptimal solution for the API answer. What you receive back is in JSON. You should find plenty of examples of how to interact with JSON here on SO. It's also specified at the top of this [API reference](https://api.mania-exchange.com/documents/reference).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Data As String = "{""TrackId"":9707620,""TrackName"":""lolsport R444""}"
        Dim dataaray() As String = Data.Split(",")
        Dim dataval() As String
        Dim fileloc As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Test.txt"
        If Not File.Exists(fileloc) Then
            File.Create(fileloc).Dispose()
        Else
            File.Delete(fileloc)
            File.Create(fileloc).Dispose()
        End If
        Dim objwriter As New StreamWriter(fileloc, True)
        Dim i As Int32 = 0
        Dim val As String
        objwriter.WriteLine("**TrackID**  **TrackName**")
        For Each rw As String In dataaray
            dataval = rw.Split(":")
            val += dataval(1).Replace("""", "").Replace("}", "") & vbTab
            If i = 1 Then
                objwriter.WriteLine(val.TrimEnd())
                val = String.Empty
                i = 0
            End If
            i += 1
        Next
        objwriter.Close()
        objwriter.Dispose()
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this it almost does what i need. I now have to figure out how i add this to a list view column and save the data in the correct format. I am trying to retrieve the data from the API i mentioned using this piece of code but then i wont sort it like it does with the single line you provided.